# Generating automatic thumbnails of recent posts

Tags: ruby, rubygems, thumbnails

Is there any gem that allows you to generate automatic thumbnails with basic info in the frontpage?
Sites like indiegogo and kickstarter have thumbnails in groups of 3 or 4 per row. Each one represent a recent post. I am trying to do something like that.

I am a ruby noobie and would also give it a try if somebody explain me how to get this done with or without a gem. I could work with ruby or javascript.

Basically the point is to create posts and have them displayed as thumbnails in the index, in groups of 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will the content come from your app? If yes, then I reckon you are looking for a way to layout your list of objects like how they did it in kickstarter and indiegogo. There are different libraries that you can use. Here are some of the libraries which you can use:

masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

isotope: https://github.com/desandro/isotope

packery: http://packery.metafizzy.co/

These libraries will help you to create brick / grid layouts.

Or, do you want to create previews from links? Then maybe this gem can help you as well: https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer

Hope this helps!